# How to revert to tabbed overview in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, customization

I recently updated my Chrome for Android (currently on v68) and noticed that tapping on the box icon (next to address bar) gives a tab list instead of SystemUI type overview that Chrome used to give. See the two images below for comparison.

I know that I can get that same view by swiping downwards from the address bar but I'm habitual of getting it from that box icon.

So what can I do to get back that view from that box **without reverting to a previous version of Chrome and without switching to an another browser (unless it is Chrome based)**?

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to uncheck the "Simplified view for open tabs" box under Settings → Accessibility in Chrome app.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 3):

Per beeshyams's [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200676/how-to-revert-to-tabbed-overview-in-chrome/200677?noredirect=1#comment256631_200690) 
 the culprit appears to be the flag Accessibility Tab Switcher. However, I also did a fresh install to reproduce the issue with all flags untouched and it was ruled out with that.

Talking about Accessibility as he mentioned, I attempted Safe Mode and found that the issue was gone. Later, I tried to stop all accessibility services under Settings → Accessibility, and using trial and error, found [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) to be the culprit causing the overview to flatten out. Stopping its service immediately solved the problem.

Comment: Type `chrome://flags` in address bar, search and disable *Accessibility Tab Switcher*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by going to chrome://flags and enabled "Enable horizontal tab switcher"...
Cheers