# I'm unable to toggle between Chrome Tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android

Earlier I used to toggle between tabs by swiping left or right and clicking on the tab I wanted to open.
But know if I click on the change tabs icon, I can only see the list like this attached image. How to get back to toggling tabs?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Please [edit] to mention Chrome Version and Android version, along with device details

Answer (score 1):

**Check if some Android accessibility settings are enabled.**

[Android accessibility settings](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006564?hl=en#) can affect an app's behavior. In Chrome's case, some settings (e.g. Switch Access) change the behavior of the tab switcher: from showing the stacked preview tabs to a simpler list shown in the question.

[image] [image]

<sup>Left: "Switch Access" disabled | Right: "Switch Access" enabled</sup>

When offending settings are enabled, Chrome will also add a new menu entry under **Settings - Accessibility - Simplified view for open tabs**. Toggling this will change the behavior of the tab switcher without needing to disable the global Android accessibility settings.

[image]

---

**Note**: it is still possible to switch to another tab by swiping *the address bar* to the left/right, even with accessibility settings enabled.

Comment: Question is possibly a dupe of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200676/96277

Comment: @Firelord ah, didn't notice I actually had upvoted both the Q&A before. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: No problem. I realized the question was a dupe of mine only after reading your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you had multiple windows open in your browser and you would have to load each page you want to switch from  in a new tab and restore them each this is something that I have been through  thanks I hope I have been able to help you