# Change Chrome Tab View/Layout

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have a problem with changing Chrome Tab View/Layout.

Before I had this tab view:

[image]

Now I have this tab view:

[image]

I don't know how and why it is changed. Perhaps, due to Chrome auto-update?

How to get back?

What I've already tried so far:

- `Chrome -> Settings -> Accessibility -> Uncheck "Simplified view for open tabs"`, but my Chrome does not have `Simplified view for open tabs`:

[image]

- `chrome://flags -> Tab Grid Layout`, but my Chrome does not have `Tab Grid Layout`:

[image]

Very confused. Need help.

Comment: "*but my Chrome does not have 'Simplified view for open tabs'*" it's only available [if other accessibility services are enabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231908/44325), though it's not the culprit for the design change.

Comment: Meanwhile, the change looks like related to [the recent redesign of using Material You](https://www.androidpolice.com/chrome-109-material-you-omnibox-redesign-stable-and-checkmark-toggles-chrome-desktop/), though I was unable to see the difference even after toggling the flag.

Comment: @AndrewT. After I enabled "Switch Access" the "Simplified view for open tabs" appeared. However, enabling the "Simplified view for open tabs" does not change the tab view/layout. Furthermore, accessing `https://www.androidpolice.com/` leads to `This page isn’t working right, www.androidpolice.com didn’t send any data., ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.